# how to achieve pinch zoom, moveable inside stack and. rotation of any widget in flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

Hello Super seniors developer. I am trying to make a post maker app like [1SStory](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onestory.storymaker&hl=en&gl=US) in flutter I want to add image or text or icon in stack and then want to make it moveable , zoom in out using 2 finger pinch and rotate .
I need same as given video example

[You can check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFEIn.gif)
I tried many solutions from stackoverflow these cases are below

***Case1***
I tried below code but it works only for make a widget moveable , I can't pinch and rotate it.

```
class MoveableStackItem extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MoveableStackItemState();
  }
}
class _MoveableStackItemState extends State<MoveableStackItem> {
  double xPosition = 0;
  double yPosition = 0;
  Color color;
  double height = 150, width = 150;
  @override
  void initState() {
    color = RandomColor().randomColor();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: yPosition,
      left: xPosition,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: (tapInfo) {
          setState(() {
            xPosition += tapInfo.delta.dx;
            yPosition += tapInfo.delta.dy;
          print(xPosition);
          });},
        child: Container(
          width: xPosition==0 ? width: xPosition,
          height: yPosition ==0? height :yPosition,
          color: color,),),);}}
```

***Case2***
I tried below code [matrix_gesture_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/matrix_gesture_detector) it use stack I can rotate, pinch and move but this is done in stack so when I do any operation like move zoom all widget get moved and zoom at once that it problem if you have any solution please guide me .

```
Stack(
        children: [
          MatrixGestureDetector(
            onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
              notifier.value = m;},
            child: AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: notifier,
              builder: (ctx, child) {
                return Transform(
                  transform: notifier.value,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Positioned.fill(
                        child: Container(
                          height: 150,
                          width: 150,
                          transform: notifier.value,
                          child: Container(height: 150,width: 150,color: Colors.yellow,),
                        ),),],),);},),),],),
```

I am stuck at from last 5 days still doing experiments butt all in vain please guide me I shall be very thank full to you .

Comment: Did you try [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html)? It allows for Pan and Pinch to zoom

Comment: I tried this but it only move between boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(100.0),

Comment: I want 3 in 1 eg moveable . pinch to zoom in zoom out and rotatable.